# I need help using a class in a function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I'm trying to convert all my mysqli over to PDO, but I'm pretty green with PDO and my problem might be elementary. I'm having trouble with the first query I'm switching over.

Here is my setup. In my login.php, I call a function like so:

**login.php**

```php
$user = attempt_login($username, $password);
```

My included functions page loads this:

**funcs.php**

```php
function attempt_login($username, $password) {
    $user = find_user_by_username($username);
    if ($user) {
        if (password_check($password, $user["salt"], $user["password"])) {
    ...
}
```

Which then refers to the function that is giving me all the errors:

```php
function find_user_by_username($username) {
    $db = new Database();
    $db->dbc();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :usr";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);               // *** this is line 157 
    $stmt->bindParam('usr', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result; 
}
```

And my class to kick things off with:

**db_connection.php**

```php
class Database 
{
    private $dbc;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $db_host = ' ';     //  hostname
            $db_name = ' ';     //  databasename
            $db_user = ' ';     //  username
            $db_pass = ' ';     //  password

            $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.'; dbname='.$db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);  
            $dbc->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
        }
        catch (PDOException $err) {  
            $err->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function dbc()
    {
        return $this->dbc;
    }

}
```

The database can connect. I just didn't want to have Globals in my function, but I feel like the error means I need some globabls in my functions page. Here is the error:

```html
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::prepare() in funcs.php on line 157
```

My question is, am i doing this all wrong meaning should I put all my functions in classes also, or am I just missing something simple? Again, I just want to use PDO in my functions and avoid using globals.

Comment: where is  :usr ?, it is the variable you want such as $db $dbc or the like, not an -> into Database, a class. You have a $db, $dbc, kinda screwed up

Comment: In your `Database::__construct()` you are setting to `$dbc` not `$this->dbc`. And then in `function find_user_by_username($username)` you need to change `$db->dbc();` to `$db = $db->dbc();`

Comment: @Sean That worked. But now I need to deal with VolkerK's suggestion. I thought I might be doing it a little wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db->dbc();
```

this has no effect since you do not store the return value in a variable and then use this variable to make the call to prepare().
Also you're not storing the PDO object in a member variable but in a local variable in the constructor method -> falls out of scope when the constructor exists.
Since your Database class does nothing but pass some parameters to the constructor of PDO it's - no offense - quite useless; and the class "doesn't do" what the name implies. I'd rather suggest using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) here.

Comment: I made both the changes Sean mentioned above and it worked, which was part of what you mentioned here. But now I need to read up on the link you mentioned. I felt I did it wrong from the beginning.